# ImageView rotation is not working properly inside the collectionView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, image-rotation

ImageView rotation is not working properly inside the collectionView cell, but outside of the collectionView it working good.It ver stretched & very thin like that it working inside the collection view

Here is my code & screens i'm getting..
For imageview inside the collection view

```
imgView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([dict[@"SomeValue"]longValue]*M_PI/180);
```

cell 0 
[image]
cell 1
[image]
cell 2
[image]

Outside of the collection view.

[image]

```
imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([dict[@"SomeValue"]longValue]*M_PI/180);
```

i don't know why it not working properly inside the collection View help me

Comment: How are you adding the image view to the cells? Could be auto layout squashing the image. Also, what is the contentMode of the image view, if you set it to centre this may solve the issue?

Comment: UIImageView *imgView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:55]; content mode is scale to fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your image size.

change the content mode